# Webpack, sass being overwriten

Tags: sass, webpack, webpack-style-loader

I'll start by saying I have a bit of a bizarre webpack build. I have 2 projects, the main project and the shared project (like a common library).

Whenever I refer to my shared project from the main project, it get some bizarre IE only/react/webpack build error where I get an error when trying to refer to my shared library. To solve this, I aliased my shared library references to the actual source on my computer in a different folder. That looks something like this:

`var alias.shared-library = 'c:\\shared-library\\index.js';`

This fixed my bizarre IE problem. However, another issue raised in my webpack production build. On the production server, the shared library exists within the node_modules folder, so I tried something like this:

`var alias.shared-library = 'node_modules\\shared-library\\index.js';`

It mostly works, except all my scss from the main project is overwritten by scss from the shared project (the output css only contains scss from the shared lib and not main). My full setup looks something like this (I removed parts I thought weren't important):

```
var SHARED_PATH = path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/shared-library');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const extractCss = new ExtractTextPlugin('css.styles.css');
const extractScss = new ExtractTextPlugin('scss.styles.css');
const plugs = [];
plugs.push(
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        __DEVELOPMENT__: false
    })
);
plugs.push(
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './index.html',
        inject: 'body',
        chunks: ['app', 'vendor']
    })
);
plugs.push(new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin());
plugs.push(
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        { from: 'src/assets', to: 'assets' },
    ])
);
plugs.push(
    new SplitByPathPlugin([
        { name: 'vendor', path: [path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')] },
    ])
);
plugs.push(extractCss);
plugs.push(extractScss);
plugs.push(
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        sourceMap: true,
        compress: {
            warnings: false
        }
    })
);
var alias = {
    'shared-library': path.resolve(SHARED_PATH, '\\src\\index.js')
};
var loaderDirs = ['node_modules', 'webpack_loaders'];
var moduleDirs = ['node_modules', 'src'];
loaderDirs.push(SHARED_PATH + '\\node_modules');
moduleDirs.push(SHARED_PATH + '\\node_modules');
moduleDirs.push(SHARED_PATH + '\\src');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: ['./src/index.js']
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.scss', '.css'],
        modulesDirectories: moduleDirs,
        alias
    },

    resolveLoader: {
        modulesDirectories: loaderDirs
    },

    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: '[name].[hash].js',
        publicPath: '/main/',
        sourceMapFilename: '[name].[hash].js.map',
        chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js',
    },

    plugins: plugs,

    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js?$/,
                loader: 'babel?sourceMaps=true',
                include: [/src/, path.resolve(SHARED_PATH, '\\src\\index.js')]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: extractCss.extract('style', 'css')
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader: extractScss.extract('style', 'css!sass'),
                include: /src/    // Trying to exclude scss from shared-library, doesn't work though
            },
            loaders.json,
            loaders.image,
            loaders.svg,
            loaders.font,
            loaders.locale,
            loaders.html
        ]
    },

    postcss: (webpack) => {
        return [
            autoprefixer({
                browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
            }),
            postcssImport({
                addDependencyTo: webpack,
            })
        ];
    },

    externals: {
        'react/lib/ReactContext': 'window',
        'react/lib/ExecutionEnvironment': 'window',
        'react/addons': true
    }
};
```

I've tried things like different permutations of exclude/include on my loaders. I thought the allChunks option on ExtractTextPlugin might work:

```
const extractScss = new ExtractTextPlugin({filename: 'scss.styles.css', allChunks: true});
```

but it just gives me this error:

```
    TypeError: path.replace is not a function
    at Template.replacePathVariables (c:\r2\RCA\rca-ui\node_modules\webpack\lib\
TemplatedPathPlugin.js:70:4)
    at Template.applyPlugins [as applyPluginsWaterfall] (c:\r2\RCA\rca-ui\node_m
odules\webpack\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:37:47)
    at Compilation.getPath (c:\r2\RCA\rca-ui\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilatio
n.js:882:27)
    at ExtractTextPlugin.<anonymous> (c:\r2\RCA\rca-ui\node_modules\extract-text
-webpack-plugin\index.js:300:29)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at ExtractTextPlugin.<anonymous> (c:\r2\RCA\rca-ui\node_modules\extract-text
-webpack-plugin\index.js:289:20)
    at Compilation.next (c:\r2\RCA\rca-ui\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\tapa
ble\lib\Tapable.js:69:14)
    at ExtractTextPlugin.<anonymous> (c:\r2\RCA\rca-ui\node_modules\extract-text
-webpack-plugin\index.js:309:4)
    at Compilation.applyPluginsAsync (c:\r2\RCA\rca-ui\node_modules\webpack\node
_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:71:13)
    at Compilation.<anonymous> (c:\r2\RCA\rca-ui\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compil
ation.js:563:8)
    at Compilation.next (c:\r2\RCA\rca-ui\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\tapa
ble\lib\Tapable.js:67:11)
    at ExtractTextPlugin.<anonymous> (c:\r2\RCA\rca-ui\node_modules\extract-text
-webpack-plugin\index.js:285:5)
    at c:\r2\RCA\rca-ui\node_modules\extract-text-webpack-plugin\node_modules\as
ync\lib\async.js:52:16
    at done (c:\r2\RCA\rca-ui\node_modules\extract-text-webpack-plugin\node_modu
les\async\lib\async.js:246:17)
    at c:\r2\RCA\rca-ui\node_modules\extract-text-webpack-plugin\node_modules\as
ync\lib\async.js:44:16
    at c:\r2\RCA\rca-ui\node_modules\extract-text-webpack-plugin\index.js:269:6
    at c:\r2\RCA\rca-ui\node_modules\extract-text-webpack-plugin\node_modules\as
ync\lib\async.js:52:16
    at done (c:\r2\RCA\rca-ui\node_modules\extract-text-webpack-plugin\node_modu
les\async\lib\async.js:246:17)
    at c:\r2\RCA\rca-ui\node_modules\extract-text-webpack-plugin\node_modules\as
ync\lib\async.js:44:16
    at c:\r2\RCA\rca-ui\node_modules\extract-text-webpack-plugin\index.js:259:9
    at c:\r2\RCA\rca-ui\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:469:4
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at callback (c:\r2\RCA\rca-ui\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:468:14
)
    at Compilation.<anonymous> (c:\r2\RCA\rca-ui\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compil
ation.js:489:4)
    at c:\r2\RCA\rca-ui\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:332:10
    at c:\r2\RCA\rca-ui\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:52:
16
    at Object.async.forEachOf.async.eachOf (c:\r2\RCA\rca-ui\node_modules\webpac
k\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:236:30)
    at Object.async.forEach.async.each (c:\r2\RCA\rca-ui\node_modules\webpack\no
de_modules\async\lib\async.js:209:22)
    at Compilation.addModuleDependencies (c:\r2\RCA\rca-ui\node_modules\webpack\
lib\Compilation.js:185:8)
    at Compilation.processModuleDependencies (c:\r2\RCA\rca-ui\node_modules\webp
ack\lib\Compilation.js:170:7)
```

Any ideas on the proper approach to solve this problem? Would the allChunks option help me here? Do I need to tighten up my include/excludes? Is there something else I'm missing? Should I give up and try and fix the IE problem another way? Is there a way I can debug what is happening? Here's the versions of the libraries I am using:

```
"extract-text-webpack-plugin": "1.0.1",
"style-loader": "0.13.0",
"sass-loader": "3.1.2",
"webpack": "1.13.2"
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do you alias your "shared" library, if you actually use it as a node module? Webpack can resolve filepaths from node modules without aliasing magic

Comment: In developer builds, we have the capability to set an environment variable (that will set alias) of where the shared-library exists in their computer, so if they're working with the main project, they can modify the shared lib directly. Do you think the alias could be causing a problem? In development build, if no shared-lib path exists, then it resolves the dependency regularly. I noted that IE only worked when the env var was set and the alias was bring used.